# SyncLock on two objects

Tags: .net, synclock

Suppose I have two objects *a* and *b*.

I want to SyncLock on both objects.

Is this feasible?  Can it be done by nested SyncLock statements?  What are the dangers of such an operation?

*Edit*

Perhaps I should ask, how can one refactor to avoid deadlocks?

Answer (score 5):

Nested locks will work - however one of the dangers is that one needs to always lock the objects in the same order, else one could cause a deadlock.

---

EDIT:
To answer the second question around trying force the correct order of locks:

A possible solution to avoid this might be to encapsulate the locking into a common lock method like this:

```
public void LockAndDoWork(Action action)
{
 lock(lockObject1)
 {
  lock(lockObject2)
  {
    action();
  }
 }
}
```

This could then be used like this:

```
Thread1: LockAndDoWork(() => {do some work....});
Thread2: LockAndDoWork(() => {do some other work...});
```

This can help avoid this potential issue - it's especially useful if one can limit visibility to those objects from client code

Comment: While this is c#, you can do the same thing in VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps I should ask, how can one refactor to avoid deadlocks?

Defining *all* sync locks in a strong order of priority and always taking the highest priority first.

This is hard: when one code block holding a lower priority lock could call into helper code that needs to take a higher priority lock significant refactoring will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do but you need to consider what happens if 2 threads running this code try to get both locks at the same time - eg if thread 1 has a lock on object 1 and thread 2 has a lock on object 2? Cue deadlock.

Someone better than I can give you some example code that should be safe :)